# make gdb load a shared library from a specific path

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

I got a core while executing an application and I saved the executable, the corefile and a shared library which the application use in `/tmp` to check them later. I then modified the library, rebuilt it and started the executable again.
Now when I am trying to debug the core, gdb is loading the shared library from its original path and not from the directory `/tmp` where I saved the original library.

For example, the original path was `/opt/mydir/lib/libmylib.so.0`.
gdb is loading this shared library, while I want it to load `/tmp/libmylib.so.0`.
The application also uses some standard libraries which are in `/usr/lib` and `/lib` directories so I don't want these paths to get changed. Just want to change `/opt/mydir/lib/` -> `/tmp`. How can I do that?

Comment: this looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66562021/1888983

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *simplest* solution is to temporarily restore `/opt/mydir/lib/libmylib.so.0` to the copy that was used at crash time (i.e. the one now in `/tmp`), analyse the core, then restore back the new version.

If you don't want to do that, `set solib-search-path` and `set sysroot` are [your friends](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html).

Note that you must set both before loading the `core`. This sequence should work:

```
(gdb) set sysroot /no/such/file
(gdb) set solib-search-path /tmp:/usr/lib:/lib
(gdb) core /tmp/core
```