# How to link specific standard library in gdb?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

When analyzing core on different machine, that binary was built for I ran into:

```
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libc.so.6" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
```

Is there a way to change which libc gdb is looking for?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886913/make-gdb-load-a-shared-library-from-a-specific-path. I've used this for application libraries but, to be honest, I don't know if it works for platform stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Kevin Boone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8471208/kevin-boone)!

`set sysroot` helped I set it to `./` and put desired libc in `./lib64` and then loaded core using `core-file`